# Having issue with heightForRowAt indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

as usual I am trying to add some custom height value to some cell with this code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height:CGFloat!

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 5:
        height =  190

    case 6:
        height = 140

    default:
        break
    }

    return height

}
```

but app crashes with this error :
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I've done this before without any problem but this time app crashes ! Why ?

Comment: If `indexPath.row` isn't 5 or 6 then you never set `height` to anything so it is still `nil`.

Comment: @dan I am sure row 5 and 6 are available, I tried with 0 , 1 and still crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate the height value

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height:CGFloat = 100

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 5:
        height =  190

    case 6:
        height = 140

    default:
        break
    }

    return height

}
```

Comment: Aha Thanks ! I forgot to add some default value

Comment: Also it's a best programming practice to only declare variables as `var` if you really intend to mutate them.  So define height as `let height: CGFloat` and in the `default` case of your switch statement set `height = 100`.  Then `height` is set once only and cannot be changed before you return it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not define `height` for rows, which are not `5` or `6`. Just define `height` as following.

```
var height: CGFloat = 100 //Or some other value you need
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases except 5 and 6 you don't set any value in `height` property. Set default value:

```
var height:CGFloat! = 100
```

or update `default` case:

```
default:
    height = 100
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value of `height` to some value. Your code is returning nil value currently.